# Resolver problemas con matrices bidimensionales (Algoritmos)

Tags: algoritmos, pseudocódigo

*En una librería se lleva el stock de libros, de cada libro se tiene: titulo, autor, categoría, stock y precio unitario. Se pide:

1) Mostrar todos los libros de la autora Ágatha Cristie, mostrar además a que categoría pertenece dicha autora y el stock valorizado total.

2) Emitir listado ordenado por categoría y autor.

3) Listar todos los libros que empiezan con “LA”. Para dicha busqueda utilizar el algoritmo de busqueda binaria.*

Si lo tuviese que resolver en base de datos sería fácil, pero me pidieron el algoritmo en **PSEUDOCÓDIGO** y no tengo la más mínima idea en como empezar más que cargando la matriz con las columnas (titulo, autor, categoría, stock, precio_unitario).
Acá tengo el primer problema porque las columnas tienen que ser del mismo tipo que la matriz (caracter en este caso) pero en uno de los puntos me piden el stock por lo cual creo que el stock se debería guardar en un vector a parte pero luego ¿como relaciono el vector con la matriz?...

Comment: ¿Por qué crees que el stock debería ser un vector? Parece que simplemente debería ser un entero que indique el número de libros que quedan.

Comment: El tipo de problema que te han planteado es muy complejo para resolverlo por Psint, el cual se emplea para la simulacion de Pseudo codigo. A la fecha actual la utima version no cuenta con permanencia de datos por lo que llevar un inventario es una tarea complicada. EL Desarrollarlo en papel el Pseudocodigo no te genera el reporte solicitado para los pasos 1,2,3 pero si mostraria la logica y contenido de los datos manejados. Te recomiendo conversar con el instructor o profesor para hacer el ejercicio en un lenguaje de programacion.

Comment: Para no liarnos con la palabra stock, entiendo que haya un Vector<Libro> para guardar todos los libros. Ahi tendrias una entrada por cada libro (el Quijote, Harry Potter...) Luego por cada libro, tendrías una variable stock de tipo entero que sería el número de libros disponibles no?

Comment: @ordago Sí, así es, porque luego tengo que mostrar el stock disponible de cada libro

Comment: @AlexanderRodriguez mientras el pseudocódigo muestre lo que se tiene qyue hacer no importa si funiona o no en PSeint, en ese caso debería defender mi pseudocódigo

Comment: @Pabli770 y cual seria el problema para escribir este pseudocodigo? al fin y al cabo, una matriz en memoria seria como una tabla de la db.. o mucho mejor.. 4 vectores en memoria serian como 4 columnas de una tabla (TIP!!!!!!)

Comment: @gbianchi no entiendo como traspasarlo a pseudo y que resuelva lo que me piden, lo podrías escribir en una respuesta como sería por favor?

Comment: En pseudo codigo es en lenguaje natural.. Algo del estilo, pedimos un dato y lo guardamos en la posicion x del array V1... pedimo otro dato y lo guardamos en la posicion x del array V2.. salvo que por pseudocodigo donde vos estas entiendan otra cosa...

Comment: @gbianchi Eso está perfecto, se sobreentiende. Lo que necesito es el pseudocódigo que resulva el problema, o al menos la forma de encararlo para poder resolverlo. Como lo resolverías vos?

Comment: Si lo resuelvo yo, la nota me la estarian poniendo a mi ;). Si en base de datos te parece facil, que haria una base de datos para resolverlo? no la instruccion, si no como resolveria el query? ese es tu pseudocodigo ;)